# jQuery: how do I convert this to 1.3.2?

Tags: jquery

```
d = $j("#sort_sections > li").map(function(index, element){
    return [[element.id,
        $j(element).find("li.content").map(function(subindex, subelement){
            return subelement.id;
        }).toArray()]];
}).toArray();
```

It currently works in 1.4.2, but I need it to work in 1.3.2 =\

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) with [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/).

They do the same thing, but [`.toArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/toArray/) was added in `jQuery 1.4`.